# Localize the range of common block variables in Fortran 77

Tags: fortran, fortran-common-block

I'm working on this F77 code with extensive use of COMMON BLOCKS, and those COMMON BLOCKS are also used in a C program (after name mangling). If foo(a, b, ...) is the main routine of the fortran code, is there anyway to make the COMMON BLOCKS local to foo() so I can do something like the following?

```
program new_control_routine()

...
call foo(a1,b1,...)
...
call foo(a2,b2,...)
...
end
```

The point is to have multiple calls of "foo" with each of them having *independent* COMMON BLOCKS, even though they those blocks have the same names. The only way I know is to rename the COMMON BLOCKS and related subroutines in the second call of "foo", so it becomes another routine "foo1", so I can do:

```
programe new_control_routine()
...
call foo(a1,b1,...)
...
call foo1(a2,b2,...)
```

But this is certainly mundane and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

The point of common blocks is that they are global, accessible to any routine that uses their name.    Could you make the variables in the common blocks arrays, and pass an index, so that your different calls accessed different elements?

Why limit yourself to FORTRAN 77?  With Fortran 95/2003 you could create a user-defined type and create a array-variable of that type.  Then you pass the index of the element that you want to work on.   The user-defined type can be a complex group of variables.   The variable can either be an argument to the subroutines or a module variable.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a legacy code and I don't have much choice but to follow what has been done in last two decades. There are hundreds of common blocks out there. And thank you for the index idea.

Comment: @taki - Unless there are other users using your code unwilling to change for reasons unknown, I see no reason why you couldn't "upgrade" it to a more recent revision (at least F90). Insisting on F77 nowadays, even by a conservative viewpoint, is unreasonable. And many users welcome when a library is upgraded to a newer revision. I'm not thinking about a rewrite, but the slow introduction of newer features of the language ...

Comment: @ldigas - Thanks. That may be something people here eventually will do.

Comment: @ldigas -- There are reasons to stick with f77.  One is that if the code uses a f77 compiler (e.g. g77) and relies on a naming convention (as I assume this code does since the common block is accessible from C as well) -- I do agree however that derived types is the way to go with this if f90 standard was deemed acceptable.

Comment: Module variables can also be shared  between Fortran and C via name.  This is supported in the ISO C Binding of Fortran.   See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperable-Global-Variables.html (while the link is to a gfortran document, this feature is more general since it is part of the language standard.)